# Sending in-memory generated .docx files from server to client with Spark

Tags: java, angularjs, docx, spark-java

I am creating a web application using the [Spark Java framework](http://sparkjava.com/). The front-end is developed using AngularJS.

I want to generate a .docx file on the server (in-memory) and send this to the client for download.

To achieve this I created an angular service with the following function being called after the user clicks on a download button:

```
functions.generateWord = function () {
    $http.post('/api/v1/surveys/genword', data.currentSurvey).success(function (response) {
        var element = angular.element('<a/>');
        element.attr({
            href: 'data:attachment;charset=utf-8;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' + response,
            target: '_blank',
            download: 'test.docx'
        })[0].click();
    });
};
```

On the server, this api call gets forwarded to the following method:

```
public Response exportToWord(Response response) {
    try {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/template.docx");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte byteStream[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        inputStream.read(byteStream);

        response.raw().setContentType("data:attachment;chatset=utf-8;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        response.raw().setContentLength((int) file.length());

        response.raw().getOutputStream().write(byteStream);
        response.raw().getOutputStream().flush();
        response.raw().getOutputStream().close();
        return response;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve this in MANY different ways and I always end up with a corrupted 'test.docx' that looks like this:

[image: corrupted word file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by using blobs and specifying the response type as 'arraybuffer' in the $http.post api call. The only bad thing with this solution (as far as I know) is that it doesn't play well with IE, but that's a problem for another day.

```
functions.generateWord = function () {
    $http.post('/api/v1/surveys/genword', data.currentSurvey, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
        .success(function (response) {
            var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'});
            var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
            var element = angular.element('<a/>');
            element.attr({
                href: url,
                target: '_blank',
                download: 'survey.docx'
            })[0].click();
        });
};
```

I think what went wrong was that the byte stream got encoded as plain text when I tried to create a URL with:

```
href: 'data:attachment;charset=utf-8;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' + response
```

thus corrupting it.

When using blobs instead, I get a "direct" link to the generated byte stream and no encoding is done on it since the response type is set to 'arraybuffer'.

Note that this is just my own reasoning of why things went wrong with the original code. I might be terribly wrong, so feel free to correct me if that's the case.